# Console.Write Freezing and stopping code from running

Tags: c#, console, .net-4.8

So, i wrote a char replacer to animate an loading scene through console, but whenever my code lands in the instruction Console.Write() it just does not continue. Didn't raised any Exception or error alert, it just stop processing and nothing happens.

```
public static void WriteSafe(int number, char[] chars)
        {
            Console.Write(chars[number]);
        }
        public static char[] Chars = new char[]
        {
            'x',
            'p',
            't',
            'o'
        };
        public static void Example(char[] chars)
        {
            while (true) //<Some Condition>
            {
                Console.CursorLeft = 1;
                int l = 0;
                if (l >= chars.Length)
                    l = 0;
                Console.CursorLeft--;
                var safeWriter = new CancellationTokenSource();
                safeWriter.CancelAfter(5000);
                var write = new Task(() => WriteSafe(l, chars), safeWriter.Token);
                try
                {
                    write.Wait();
                }
                catch
                {
                    continue;
                }

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(600);
                l++;
            }

        }
public static void Main()
{
    Example(Chars);
}
```

If i didn't setup a Cancellation Token and async task, the debugger will load the Console.Write(), wouldn't complete it and, never gets out of it
(.NET 4.8)

Comment: Why are you changing the value of `Console.CursorLeft`? You set it to 1, then decrement it to 0 on every loop. I have a feeling you are simply overwriting your chars, since you never wrap your lines and never let the cursor advance beyond 0. BTW, why are you putting a method to write a single character in a new thread? If you want to use a separate thread, I would think the "Example" method would be the target.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. I did it only for the example to work. The main program work as you just said. The problem still happens. Outside the example, there's only a simple void method that does it.

Comment: Putting the code into an online C# compiler, I realized that you are initializing your "l" variable to 0 every loop, which would only display "x". I also had the catch put the exception into a variable and print out the exception message, which was "One or more errors occurred. (A task was canceled.)", so you should add breakpoints and also print out the exception to help you debug your issue. I found that modifying `Console.CursorLeft` had no effect, once I got it working without creating a separate thread and just called "WriteSafe" directly.

Comment: The Console.CursorLeft--; was meant to replace the current char and give the ilusion of an animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To continue the debugging and feedback I started in the comments, the `Task` needs to have more than just the `Wait` method run. You need to call the `Start` method. Since the method you call is so small, you don't even have to call `Wait`. In fact, because your method is so small, you can put it in a call to `Run` instead and not use the "write" or "safeWriter" variables unless you are going to be using them for something much more complicated later.

```
Task.Run( () => Console.Write(chars[l]));
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming

And to include what I said in the comments:

- Modifying `Console.CursorLeft` isn't necessary as it doesn't do anything
- Move the creation of the "l" variable out of your loop
- Add breakpoints and print out exception messages to help you debug your code